# Not able to download file. Giving Exception

Tags: c#, azure, zip

I am trying to download multiple file in zip formate using zipOutputStream.
Its Giving Exception in blob.DownloadToStream(zipOutputStream); line

```
List<string> lstPath = DAL_AttachmentSQLHelper.GetAllAttachementPath(claimId);            
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
            var container = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("traveoappclaimattachments/Traveo1");           
            using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream))
            {
                foreach (var blobFileName in lstPath)
                {
                    zipOutputStream.SetLevel(0);
                    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFileName);
                    var entry = new ZipEntry(blobFileName);
                    zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                    blob.DownloadToStream(zipOutputStream);
                }
                zipOutputStream.Finish();
                zipOutputStream.Close();
            }
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "zipFileName.zip");
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome. Please also share the **exact** exception that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I see with your code is how you're creating an instance of `CloudBlobContainer` in your code. Assuming your container name is `traveoappclaimattachments` and all the files are located in `Traveo1`, you could try something like below:

```
List<string> lstPath = DAL_AttachmentSQLHelper.GetAllAttachementPath(claimId);            
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
var container = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("traveoappclaimattachments");           
using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream))
{
    foreach (var blobFileName in lstPath)
    {
        zipOutputStream.SetLevel(0);
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Traveo1/" + blobFileName);
        var entry = new ZipEntry(blobFileName);
        zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
        blob.DownloadToStream(zipOutputStream);
    }
    zipOutputStream.Finish();
    zipOutputStream.Close();
}
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "zipFileName.zip");
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Gaurav Mantri ....I tried Like this Also but getting Exception in blob.DownloadToStream(zipOutputStream) i.e The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: That could mean 2 things: Either the container doesn't exist or the blob doesn't exist. Can you check if the blobs indeed exist in the container/virtual folder? Please edit your question and share a screenshot of the files you see in this virtual folder (Traveo1).